# Where is the SMS "Drafts" folder on the Xperia Play?

Tags: sms, sony-ericsson-xperia-play

The manual says when typing a text, if you stop to answer a call, whatever you were typing is placed into a "Draft" folder or is saved as a draft. The thing is, that I have never seen or found any "Draft" location other then when I use the browser to go online and goto my email site, and hat isn't where its going.

I was typing a huge text and I am really upset that I will have to re-type the entire thing, knowing it is in my phone somewhere, unless the manual from Sony Ericsson written specifically for this phone is totally wrong. Even though the manual says it is saved, it also is too vague on conveying where this draft folder is.

Can any one help me? This had been am ongoing issue and this "unfinished draft" location must have 400 messages in it by now. I am totally confused. The manual said to goto the "Time Save" app but I don't even think that's correct.

Answer (score 2):

There's no drafts folder per say, when you access your SMS APP, the conversations list appears:

- If a draft is present on any conversation thread, you will see "draft" written in red. Tap and you're back on your draft.
- If it was an SMS with no conversation thread, it is presented the same way.

Check your Phone's manual, [page 39](http://www-support-downloads.sonymobile.com/r800/userguide_EN_R800_1248-2319.2.pdf), where it reads:

> If you exit a message before sending, it gets saved as a draft. If the message is part of a conversation, the conversation gets tagged with the word Draft.

[image: Manual Page 35]